# Simplification of Complex Number (Summation?) with Bra-Ket-like Notation

Tags: complex-numbers

I've been working through the problem sets for the Feynman Lectures on Physics and found a question on complex numbers that I'm having a hard time solving. It asks for the student to calculate the magnitude of $A$ within the following equation.

[Image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgPR1.png)

I think I'm having a problem firstly, because I have made the assumption that what looks like half of a bra-ket is some sort of summation and secondly given this assumption, I can't simplify the expression into the answer desired which is:

$|A| = \frac{r \sin(N+1)\theta/2}{\sin(\theta/2)}$

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: I think it's a sum (probably misprinted). Also, this is a geometric series. What is the first term and common ratio?

Comment: Ah yep makes sense -- thanks so much : )

Comment: Delete question, then?